# Where can I find Masechet Sofrim online?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet

I'm looking to be able to download the minor tractate Sofrim, but I've been unable to find a place to do so. Where can I find it?

Comment: http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_(%D7%93%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A1_%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%9D_%D7%AA%22%D7%93)/%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%9C

Comment: @DoubleAA sounds like an answer to me; why not post it as such?

Comment: Avram, Did you try searching Google? [https://www.google.com/search?q=מסכת+סופרים](https://www.google.com/search?q=מסכת+סופרים)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you search the Sefer title 'מסכת סופרים'  on Hebrewbooks.org you will have more results, here is a link to one of them. http://hebrewbooks.org/20355

Answer (score 3):

You can also access Sofrim [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Tractate_Soferim?lang=bi) at Sefaria. I prefer Sefaria to Hebrewbooks since the former is much more flexible in copying/pasting and linking other sources than Hebrewbooks.